# Whatsapp Business Api- Message template are going after 30mins

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

[https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/{{Phone-Number-ID}}/messages](https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/%7B%7BPhone-Number-ID%7D%7D/messages)

Headers contains Authentication token

passing json body:

```
{
  "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
   "recipient_type": "individual",
  "to": "{{Recipient-Phone-Number}}",
  "type": "template",
  "template": {
    "name": "ticket_confirmation",
    "language": {
      "code": "en"
    },
    "components": [
      {
        "type": "header",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "image",
            "image": {
              "link": "https://link.png"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "body",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "xyz"
          },
          {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "event name"
          },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "2"
          },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "text": "ticketname"
        },
        {       
            "type": "date_time",
            "date_time": {
              "fallback_value": "May 10, 2023"
            }
        },
        {   
            "type": "text",
            "text": "18:30 - 23:30"
        },
        {   
            "type": "text",
            "text": "location"
        },
          {
            "type": "currency",
            "currency": {
              "fallback_value": "value",
              "code": "INR",
              "amount_1000": 2100630
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am getting this in response

```
"messages": [
    {
        "id": "wamid.HBgMOTE3MDQyMjY2ODExFQIAERgSQkQ0MDMyRTYyNTdBNUJGM0M0AA=="
    }
]
```

I am hitting this API to send my message templates to the user who have purchased tickets on my platform but the message are going after 30mins(before i was getting the message withing secs.

Comment: It is sent means there is no issue on your side, there are possibilities for issues in the cloud API platform, many people faced similar issues, check [the forum](https://developers.facebook.com/community?sort=newest&category=766772797555412)

Comment: @turivishal Okay thankyou. Lets see when they fix this issue as there are no solutions yet

Comment: Follow the reported bug they are still investigating and demanding the more debugging details https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/587271766844244/?join_id=f12ad04dbf8564